# html5 app freezes in ios13 after navigating to an external url in in-app standalone safari browser and back

Tags: freeze, iphone-x, iphone-standalone-web-app, ios13.4, ios-web-app

**Issue**

My web application built using nuxt and installed as web app on iphone becomes unresponsive after I open or visit an external link from the app. Issue specifically comes iOS 13.4 and above on real devices. Simulators works fine.

**Devices**

iPhone X and XI (all versions) with iOS 13.4 and above

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Open url https://nuxt-min-pwa.netlify.app/ in safari.
2. Tap on **share icon** and then **add to home screen**.
3. Open app from home screen.
4. Tap on **menu icon**.
5. Tap on **second**.
6. Tap on link named ICE.
7. App will open an external url.
8. Tap on **Back to App** button to return to the app.
9. Tap on **second** now.
10. App does not responds. A thin loading bar seems to be in progress, everytime **second** is tapped. But nothing else happens.

Web app is working fine in iphone8 with ios 13.3.1 and Xcode simulators. There is a similar issue reported on both stack overflow and apple developer forum. Although it specifically mentions microsoft openid, but I am sure, issue comes up with any external url.

[PWA freezing on navigation clicks in Safari iOS (13.5) after OpenID Microsoft sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461672/pwa-freezing-on-navigation-clicks-in-safari-ios-13-5-after-openid-microsoft-si)
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649699

Source code for app
https://github.com/appsbuddha/minimal-nuxt-pwa