# Angular Service Worker stuck in Safari after logout

Tags: mobile-safari, angular-service-worker

We have a WebApp developed with Angular 14. It is deployed on Azure Blob Storage (static website).
Authentification is done with the [msal library for javascript](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular). Azure AD B2C is used as identity provider.

When we logout we call `msalService.logoutRedirect()` which works fine for all devices except for iPhones using the Safari browser. On iPhone/Safari it *sometimes* gets stuck (mostly when we had the phone locked for a few minutes first). Safari then displays a "neverending" network request - but I am convinced that the actual problem is some code in the service worker, as Safari gets completely frozen and you cannot even enter anything in the Console.

We are using [Angular Service Worker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro) to provide a PWA and everything is working fine if we serve the app without Service Workers.

I tried to take a look at `ngsw/state` (which usually works) but as soon as the bug occurs, this site is not reachable (I assume because Safari is stuck).

For me this looks like the service worker code is stuck in some loop (there are no errors shown in the console). When I then manually try to reload the page we get the following errors in the console: [image: console errors after reloading].

How can I find out what causes the problem here? I tried to debug the `ngsw-worker.js` file but it's almost 2k lines, so it's not that easy. Is there any simpler way to debug it?

**Update:**
This is how the `ngsw-config.json` looks like:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

We are using google-fonts and fetch it from `fonts.googleapis.com`.
When we logout and the bug occurs the browser displays that it tries to load the google fonts - it is stuck there. Is it possible that it somehow thinks the google-fonts file should be in cache and it tries to fetch it but since it isn't there, it loads endlessly?

Update: I found a forum post that sounds very similar to the problem we have, unfortunately, it seems they never found a solution: [apple forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649699)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to clone the msal library and change the code [in the navigation client](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/2810c287c415c240a0e4fd82946e38a1d84d4d42/lib/msal-browser/src/navigation/NavigationClient.ts#L33) to always use replace instead of assign. Could be worth a shot since it helped me in the react oidc library i used.